# SQL insert query convert to C# add records

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, oracle-sqldeveloper

i want convert Oracle developer tables to C# add table static record exmple as below

Insert into Emp(Id,Name,Age) values(1,sam,22); convert to context.emp.add(Id=1,Name=sam,Age=22);

Comment: I suggest you read a tutorial on EF Core and ORMs in general. This has **nothing** to do with exposing tables in code as if this was SQL/J.  Think Hibernate and JPA, not Oracle Developer. An ORM Maps Objects to Relational constructs. On the object side you have your application's entities, not tables. DbContext is neither a database model, nor a connection. It's a Unit-of-Work, containing *only* the entities needed for a specific scenario/use case. If you have many scenarios, you have many DbContexts with different entities

Comment: Start with the [EF core - Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli) tutorial.